# Selenium: Opening chrome browser catching Errors

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When trying open chrome browser by `webdriver.Chrome()`, it return **errors**:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49645/devtools/browser/3c3d566d-8283-456e-9cae-4de285cd025e
PS C:\Users\Stellantt\Desktop\Selenium> [7896:6536:1114/074848.328:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[7896:6536:1114/074848.328:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[7896:6536:1114/074848.328:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no 
report that this ends.
[7896:6208:1114/074848.334:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [07:48:48.334] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device 
attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[7896:6536:1114/074848.342:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[4920:3584:1114/075045.724:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

When I used options to fix it:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

It returned nothing at all and terminated my process.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

These error messages...

```
PS C:\Users\Stellantt\Desktop\Selenium> [7896:6536:1114/074848.328:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[7896:6536:1114/074848.328:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[7896:6536:1114/074848.328:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no 
report that this ends.
[7896:6208:1114/074848.334:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [07:48:48.334] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device 
attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[7896:6536:1114/074848.342:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[4920:3584:1114/075045.724:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

......are the result of a generic bug as the *parametrized tests are flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup*

These errors/warnings doesn't affects the test execution and you can ignore them as of now.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Issue 1216328: Parametrized tests are flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1216328)